# LinkedIn API does not open the login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, linkedin-api

Vue.js

```
 async signInWithLinkedIn() {
  console.log("Sign In Clicked!")
  try {
    const response = await CustomerProfileService.signInLinkedIn()
    if(response.data.error != null){
      this.error = 'Please try again.'
    }else{
      this.error = 'Successful.'
    }
  } catch (error) {
    //this.error = error.response.data.error
  }
}
```

Node.js

```
var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')('aaaa', 'bbbb')
    async signInLinkedIn (req, res) {
        //var scope = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
        // This will ask for permisssions etc and redirect to callback url.
        Linkedin.auth.setCallback('http://localhost:4172/linkedInCallBack')
        //Linkedin.auth.authorize(res, scope)
        Linkedin.auth.authorize(res)
    }
```

I am using the `node-linkedin` package to get some LinkedIn data from user. So when the nodejs code runs, there is no error but it does not redirect me to the login page where I will approve the request. How can I fix this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: your `catch(error){}` hides errors --- are you sure there's not an error?

Comment: No error because it ran this line instead: this.error = 'Successful.' @CodyG.

Comment: I am able to see the LinkedIn redirect URL in my Network (press F12) but it is just not redirecting. @CodyG.

Comment: Is it expected that you are supposed to redirect it using javascript? `window.location = "http://www.example.com/";` Can you provide the API you're looking at?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin @CodyG.

Comment: I would try using the exact express example they provide `app.get(...)` and if that doesn't work then go from there... sorry couldn't be of more help!